# Issue loading style sheet in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx-8

I am developing an application on Linux using OpenJDK 8u20 and OpenJFX 8u5. I am basically trying to set a default style sheet for all scenes. There apparently isn't a a sanctioned way to do that, so the work around is to set the style sheet for each individual scene. The way to do this is "scene.getStylesheets().add(css)" where css is a String representing the location of the style sheet. That representation can be in three flavors: file, URL, or resource.

An example of the URL approach is:

```
String css = "http://localhost/file.css";
```

An example of the file approach is:

```
String css = "file://" + new File("file.css").getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/");
```

An example of the resource is:

```
String css = this.getClass().getResource("file.css").toString();
```

Of the three, only the URL approach appears to work as advertised.

The file approach appears to work initally, but subsequent compiles appears to break it. I can see that "scene.getStylesheets().add(css)" is being called with the correct value, but the application runs as if it never was. It only works after the compile that I edit the file that I am adding the stylesheet. If I edit any other file, compile, and run it does not work.

The resource approach just throws a runtime exception, namely "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)".

I have a work around for now by using the URL approach, but long term I would really like to be able to package that CSS file in the jar and use it from the jar. Does anybody have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I forgot to mention that every permutation I can think of for getClass().getResource("file.css") always returns null.

Answer (score 0):

OK, apparently I didn't understand how the resource approach is supposed to work sufficiently. I compile the class files in a temporary directory, and I was not also copying the resource files to that directory. Once I did that getResource starting working. So now both the URL and resource approaches are working for me.

If anybody wants to comment on the odd behavior of the file approach, it would be nice to know what's up with that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of setting a default CSS style sheet for all of your scenes and you can accomplish that by invoking the static setUserAgentStyleSheet() method on the JavaFx Application.

Comment: That completely replaces the style sheet, not just adds some tweaks. Using the file approach with setUserAgentStyleSheet() was also exhibiting the same odd behavior, but now that I have the resource approach working I might use setUserAgentStyleSheet() with a modified version of the default css.